# Pass input value through PHP parameter

Tags: php

I haven't had much success searching my problem on google.
I'm a junior Developer. A point in the right direction or any help will be  much appreciated thank you.

I have a PHP function called autocomplete.

```
$search = autocomplete('products',$search_term);

<input value="<?=$search_term; ?>" onkeydown="$search" type='text' name='product'>
```

If I set the parameters without a variable it works. but I need it to be a variable so onkeydown the search term updates and runs the function again.

When the input value changes it must run $search again every time. But I cant figure out how to make the variable equal to the input value. So that My function parameter updates when it changes.

Do I have to use javascript for this or is there a way to just set the value equal the value inserted into my input field?

Comment: You have to use javascript/ajax for this. Btw; `onkeydown="$search"` is out fo scope of your php application and will do nothing

Comment: You need both javascript and php to achieve this you are trying to do

Comment: Whatever you write inside the value of the onkeydown attribute is javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I have modified your input field

```
<input class="product" value="" onkeydown="Search(this.value)" type='text' name='product'>
```

I added a jquery function `Search()` to get the value of the input field with class `product` on key down and send it to the php file. (Let's assume the php file is `search.php`)

```
<script>
//Dont forget to include jquery on your page

function Search(value){


$.ajax({
   url: 'search.php',
   data:{product:value},
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data)
   },
   type: 'POST'
});
}
```

Then in file `search.php`, we do this

```
//search.php
//I assume this is where your function autocomplete is defined
$search_item =$_POST['product'];
$search = autocomplete('products',$search_term);
```

Hope you get the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="autocomplete(this.value)">

<script>
function autocomplete(value) {
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

pass value like this!

Answer (score 0):

The others are right.
PHP is a Serverside language. So u can't do things like u make.

What happen.
PHP Proceed a Script -> Output is HTML.
This is sending to the Client (Browser).
U can do things there and with a Form or others send a new Request to the Server. And PHP Proceed a new Output.

What the others try to say.

U should use JS. Then the script fires request to your server without reloading your full website.

You should look for: jQuery, ajax, xhr